# How can I modify an existing column into a foregin key in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Given for example the following:

```
CREATE TABLE agency(agency_id, agency_name)
  AS VALUES (1,'Test Agency');

CREATE TABLE employee(employee_id,agency,first_name)
  AS VALUES (16,'Test Agency','Paul');

Desired output:

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      employee_id    |      agency_id   |     first_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          15         |         1        |       Paul       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I populated the Employee table from a JSON using `ogr2ogr` and naturally it wouldn't catch that the agency value is supposed to be referenced from the Agency table.

How can I `ALTER` or `UPDATE` the existing column `agency` in Employee table to take the `agency_id` of the Agency table and change its type as foreign key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure you have no duplicate `agency_names`, or you may have problems.

```
SELECT agency_name
FROM agency
GROUP BY agency_name
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Make sure your primary key is set on agency,

```
ALTER TABLE agency
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (agency_id);
```

Then wrap the modifications all in a transaction.

```
BEGIN;

    ALTER TABLE employee
      ADD COLUMN agency_id int
      REFERENCES agency;
    UPDATE employee
      SET agency_id = a.agency_id
      FROM agency AS a
      WHERE employee.agency = a.agency_name;
    ALTER TABLE employee
      DROP COLUMN agency;

COMMIT;
```

Output,

```
TABLE employee ;
 employee_id | first_name | agency_id 
-------------+------------+-----------
          16 | Paul       |         1
(1 row)
```

**Note** I assumed you wanted the primary key on the `agency_id` based on the wording of the question. You can, as @Craig Ringer points out, create an FKEY using the text of the column too. That column will still have to be unique -- see the above. Doing so would look like this,

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  ON agency (agency_name);
ALTER TABLE employee
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (agency)
  REFERENCES agency(agency_name);
```

Comment: Note that you can, if you wish, instead declare a `FOREIGN KEY` check on the existing column `employee.agency`. Nothing *requires* you to use a surrogate key, though it's often more efficient to do so.

Comment: @CraigRinger updated to show that too. (though that's not how I read the question)

Comment: @EvanCarroll I'll test this out! thank you for this detailed answer and options  fom Craig:)